# How to fix CA1051 on fields in xaml code?

Tags: silverlight, code-analysis, fxcop

I am running FxCop against my Silverlight code and appear to be getting a lot of CA1051 error codes:

```
Error, Certainty 90, for DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields

Target       : #msgTextBox  (IntrospectionTargetMember)
Resolution   : "Because field 'MessagingControl.msgTextBox' is 
               visible outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility 
               to private and add a property, with the same accessibility 
               as the field has currently, to provide access to it."
Help         : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182141(VS.100).aspx  (String)
Category     : Microsoft.Design  (String)
CheckId      : CA1051  (String)
RuleFile     : Design Rules  (String)
Info         : "Instance fields that are visible outside of the type 
               that declares them, limit your ability to change the 
               implementation details for those data items. Use properties 
               instead. They do not compromise usability or performance 
               and they do provide flexibility in that they conceal 
               the implementation details of the underlying data."
Created      : 25/11/2011 10:59:54  (DateTime)
LastSeen     : 25/11/2011 14:57:49  (DateTime)
Status       : Active  (MessageStatus)
Fix Category : NonBreaking  (FixCategories)
```

Most of these seem to be from `x:Name` in the xaml so I don't think it can be fixed? Is there anything I can do to fix these errors apart from suppressing them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default visibility for control fields is set to internal.

use  `x:FieldModifier="<modifier>"` e.g.  `<TextBox x:Name="msgTextBox" x:FieldModifier="private" />` to control this behavior.

Comment: Well, simple and easy fix! Thank you very much. The other thing I found is that the alternative in many of these cases is to remove the x:Name altogether if it's unused as that seems to remove another warning